# Gurobi Python Error (NoneType has no len())

Tags: python, typeerror, nonetype, gurobi

I need to write an optimization file for Gurobi (Python) that is a modified version of a classic TSP. I tried to run the example file from their website:

examples.gurobi.com/traveling-salesman-problem/

I always get the following error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

What do I need to change?
Thx

Full code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ewisx805b3o2wq5/beispiel_opt.py?dl=0

Comment: Can you include the code and what line you get the error on?

Comment: Full code added. Get the error in line 16 and 82

Comment: @DEM I don't know whether it is related but line 45 at your code is not equal with the code on the website. There is an extra indent for return on your code.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the error with the example code from Gurobi's website. At the first look the problem seems to be inside the `subtour` function, that returns `None` if `sum(lengths) == n`  and the missing check for if `tour` is `None` inside the `subtourlim` function.

Instead of providing a fix for the specific code, I first checked the examples that Gurobi installs inside the specific installation directory:

- Mac: `/Library/gurobi810/mac64/examples/python/`
- Linux: `/opt/gurobi800/linux64/examples/python/`
- Windows: `c:\gurobi800\win64\examples\python\`

And surprisingly the `tsp.py` from there runs without any errors. Note also that the two mentioned functions are revised. So I guess the example from the website is just a old version of the code.

Comment: Thank you so much! I took the newest Version and it worked